# How to implement Picture-in-picture in reactjs using jitsimeet vide conference

Tags: reactjs, jitsi-meet, picture-in-picture

I created a video meeting feature in a React.js web app using Jitsi meet. But I am trying to implement the picture-in-picture feature so the video calling page can be minimised and the app can be used while the meeting is still on.

```
import React from "react";
import { JitsiMeeting } from "@jitsi/react-sdk";
const Appointments = () => {
  return (
   
          <div className="h-full" id="pip-meet">
            <JitsiMeeting
              roomName="Temple Appointment"
              configOverwrite={{
                startWithAudioMuted: true,
                disableModeratorIndicator: true,
                startScreenSharing: false,
                enableEmailInStats: false
              }}
              interfaceConfigOverwrite={{
                DISABLE_JOIN_LEAVE_NOTIFICATIONS: false
              }}
              userInfo={{
                displayName: "name",
                email: details.email
              }}
              onApiReady={(externalApi: any) => {
              }}
              onReadyToClose={() => {
                setJoinCall(false);
              }}
              getIFrameRef={(iframeRef: any) => {
                iframeRef.style.height = "100%";
              }}
            />
          </div>
          )}
export default Appointments;
```

When I wrap my jitsimeeting component with a video element so the picture-in-picuture mode can be accessed, it doesn't show my meeting component at all, but if I change the video element to a div or react fragment it shows the jitsimeeting component but picture-in-picuture isn't available because it can only be targeted by a video element I guess. Any help or experience with this is appreciated.